# How to set Char 'S' to $80 - Java

Tags: java

i want to set Char 'S' to $80
   when it ask user to enter the car size they should enter 'S', 'M' or 'L' and display the output on the string "Daily hire rate: $80", if they type 'M' it should display "Daily hire rate: $100"

give me a example how to set char 'S' to $80

```
package carRental;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Stage2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = getInput("Enter Customer Name: ");
        String s2 = getInput("Enter Customer Address: ");
        String s3 = getInput("Enter Customer phone No: ");
        String s4 = getInput("Enter Customer License No: ");
        String s5 = getInput("Enter Credit Card No: ");
        String s6 = getInput("Enter Expiry Date: ");
        String s7 = getInput("Enter Hire Length (in days): ");
        String s8 = getInput("Enter Make/Model of Assigned Vehicle: ");
        String s9 = getInput("Enter Registration No of Assigned Vehicle: ");
        String s11 = getInput("Enter Car Size - (S)mall, (M)edium or (L)arge: ");
        String s12 = getInput("Enter Days Hired: ");

        double hirerate = Double.parseDouble(s11);
        int noofdays = Integer.parseInt(s7);
        double result = hirerate * noofdays;        

        System.out.println("Customer Details: ");
        System.out.println("Name: " + s1);
        System.out.println("Address: " + s2);
        System.out.println("Phone Number: " + s3);
        System.out.println("License No: " + s4);
        System.out.println("Credit Card No: " + s5);
        System.out.println("Expiry Date: " + s6); 
        System.out.println("Car Hire Details: ");
        System.out.println("Make/Model: " + s8);    
        System.out.println("Registration No: " + s9);   
        System.out.println("Hire Length (days): " + s7);    
        System.out.println("Daily Hire Rate: " + s11);
        System.out.println("Basic Hire Charge: " + result);
        System.out.println("Days Hired: " + s12);
        System.out.println("Late Return Surcharge: ");
        System.out.println("Adjusted Hire Charge: ");


    }

    private static String getInput(String prompt) {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print(prompt);
        System.out.flush();

        try {
            return stdin.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: An easy way to do this would be creating another function which would be called when the daily hire rate is prompted, in which you could include the necessary algorithm to print out the daily hire depending on the value of s11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Switch Operator`.

```
char c = /* whatever */;

switch(c) {
case 's':
case 'S':
    //Your conditions here for S
    break;
case 'm':
case 'M':
    //Your conditions here for M
    break;
// (...)
case 'l':
case 'L':
    //Your conditions here for L
    break;
```

}

or you could just normalize to lower case or upper case before switching.

`char c = Character.toUpperCase(/* whatever */);`

Answer (score 0):

```
String rate(final char type) {
    switch (Character.toUpperCase(type)) {
    case 'S':
        return "$60";
    case 'M':
        return "$80";
    case 'L':
        return "$100";
    default:
        System.err.println("No valid entry for " + type);
        return "";//or throw 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bob sorry, I first wrote it for a String value, and carelessly changed to char... Should work now